# Regular expressions src="http"

Tags: regex

I have the following string and I need a regular expression for mysql to find "something"

```
<img alt="" src="http://something/sites/default/files/product_content" />
```

I have tried:

```
SELECT `regex_replace`('src="http://([^/]+)/teo/sites/default/files/', 'whatIWant', '<p>        <img alt="" src="http://something/teo/sites/default/files/product_content/img"/></p>');
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not in a place where I can test it but try something like this:
`@src=['"]http://([^/]+)/@`

Use the `@` symbol to surround your pattern instead of traditional slashes so you don't have to escape every slash.
Look for `"` or `'` after `src=` because single quotes are valid too.
Search for `http://` followed by (NOT a slash character, one or more)
After that look for a slash character.

So, the short story is it's easier to search for NOT a slash than try to search for every character that could appear in the domain name.

Comment: Yes, but I using the RegExp in mysql and ['"] not work. The script is something like this

SELECT `regex_replace`('src="http://([^/]+)/teo/sites/default/files', 'src="http://niko/sites/default/files', '<p><img alt="" src="http://localhost/teo/sites/default/filges/product_content/img/></p>');

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your `something` may have dots in it since it looks like a domain, so this is the PHP regex you want to use
`'%http://([\w\.]*)/sites/default/files%im'`